# Left shoulder higher than the right one. Pull Up

Tags: stretching, pull-ups, shoulders, mobility

I will just post this screenshot about a video i made today. i saw similar discussion here about it can be just strength problem or it can be a spine problem. If u have any advice (also if u think to do an RX) i'll appreciate. Thanks[image]

Comment: Oscar - Welcome to the site! I would encourage you to take [the tour](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help). We expect questions to be answerable, and I don't really see that in your posting. Additionally, we can't give medical evaluations or advice. As such, I'm going to be closing your question. If you can edit it to a better question within our guidelines, it can be nominated for reopening.

Comment: @JohnP We've seen this one before, I've switched this over to a duplicate. Oscar, if the linked question doesn't address what you're asking, let us know and we can work on clarifying what your concern is.